# Fractional derivative notation in wave turbulence

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, schrodinger-operators, fractional-calculus, wave-equation

This is my first question in MathOverflow and I will do my best to format it correctly and make it clear.

I am reading a paper on dispersive wave turbulence which introduces the following family of equations:

$$i\psi_t=|\partial_x|^{\alpha}\psi+|\partial_x|^{-\beta/4}\left(\left||\partial_x|^{-\beta/4}\psi\right|^2|\partial_x|^{-\beta/4}\psi\right)$$

Where $|\cdot|$ denotes the $L^2$ norm in relevant places. This equation is stated to have the dispersion relation $\omega=|k|^{\alpha}$ and becomes an NLS equation when $\alpha=2$ and a water-like dispersion law when $\alpha=1/2$.

I am not terribly comfortable with fractional derivatives, and in my Googling have been unable to find the use of the particular absolute value notation in $|\partial_x|^{\alpha}$. Could anyone help me interpret the equation above or point me towards a solid source?

Many thanks in advance!

(reference: https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-one-dimensional-model-for-dispersive-wave-Majda-McLaughlin/75056874558c915a68f9cb53fc0dc989148e6db5)

Comment: I guess [this](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-one-dimensional-model-for-dispersive-wave-Majda-McLaughlin/75056874558c915a68f9cb53fc0dc989148e6db5) is the paper you are referring to?

Comment: Yes it is, I should add it to the question.

Comment: The absolute value of the fractional derivative is defined with respect to the Fourier transform, so that the Fourier transform of $|\partial_x|^\alpha f(x)$ is $|k|^\alpha f(k)$.

Comment: I see, so you would say they are not working with the explicit form of the equation but rather using it as a stepping stone to the transformed equation?

Comment: Do you know of a reasonably succinct source where I could read up on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fractional derivative $|\partial_x|^\alpha$ is discussed in [One-dimensional wave turbulence](https://maths.ucd.ie/~dias/ZakharovDiasPushkarev.pdf) by Zakharov, Dias, and Pushkarev. (Zakharov introduced the notation.) As they explain below Eq. 2.1, it is indeed defined via the Fourier transform, such that the Fourier transform of $|\partial_x|^\alpha\psi(x)$ is $|k|^\alpha\psi(k)$. Their appendix A contains a few more details.

Comment: Thank you, this provides a good starting point.